# Issue with passing variables to FMDB

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, fmdb

In my app I'm using `FMDB` to query my `sqlite` database. I'm passing variables from one view to another and at the end all the selections the variables are filled with the values selected. On the results page I can show these values in label's fine. But the moment I pass them to `FMDB` to query the database I don't get any values returned. It crashes and says that the array is 0 which I know it's not.

**Code sample below.**

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getChoices
{
  NSMutableArray *choices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
  [db open];

  NSString *capsChoiceOne = @"CHOICE 1";
  NSString *capsChoiceTwo = @"CHOICE 2";
  NSString *capsChoiceThree = @"CHOICE 3";
  NSString *capsChoiceFour = @"CHOICE 4";

  FMResultSet *results = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM allitems WHERE choice1=%@ AND choice2=%@ AND choice3=%@ AND choice4=%@"
                        ,capsChoiceOne,capsChoiceTwo,capsChoiceThree,capsChoiceFour];

while([results next])
{
    Choices *choice = [[Choices alloc] init];

    choice.result = [results stringForColumn:@"result"];

    [choices addObject:choice];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Result"
                                                    message:choice.result
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

[db close];

return choices;
```

Now the above code will bring back the result in the Alert View. But the moment I change one of the values to a variable it crashes and say's there was 0 results in my array. I've put the code below for how I'm inserting the variable.

```
NSString *capsChoiceOne = self.choiceOneSelected.uppercaseString;
```

the `self.choiceOneSelected.uppercaseString` contains the same as the hard coded version but doesn't work.

Any help would be grateful.

Thank you

Comment: For one thing you're inserting results into choices and then returning pipcodes.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had changed all the code for the example. Thank you I have amended the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether  `self.choiceOneSelected.uppercaseString;` is not `nil`.

Also your query have some issues, **you need to wrap `string` values inside `'`**

So use:

```
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM allitems WHERE choice1='%@' AND choice2='%@' AND choice3='%@' AND choice4='%@'"
                        ,capsChoiceOne,capsChoiceTwo,capsChoiceThree,capsChoiceFour];
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestions but unfortunately putting ' ' around the strings seems to break it. Also I've stepped through and     `self.choiceOneSelected.uppercaseString;` is being populated. It just doesn't seem to be getting passed to the query.

Comment: @Flyingearl: Never put " (double quote) put ' (single quote)

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake I forgot to put a space between them. I was using single quotes. Sorry for being mis-leading. I've edited my orignal response.

Comment: @Flyingearl: Still have issue ? Can you please NSLog the query and check whether it is correct ?

Comment: It seems to be working now. I changed a few things about and noticed that one of my variables was stored under the wrong name and hadn't noticed until now. Think I may need to take a break as clearly I'm not seeing straight. Thank you for your help as it made me think :).

Comment: @MidhunMP This is not correct. You say "you need to wrap string values inside '". That would be correct if you were manually building the SQL with `NSString` method `stringWithFormat`. But this is not how FMDB's `executeQueryWithFormat` works. Somewhat curiously, `executeQueryWithFormat` is replacing the printf-style `%` sequences with `?` placeholders, and then binding values to those `?` placeholders. So, when using `executeQueryWithFormat`, do _not_ wrap string percent sequences with `'` characters. But do so if you're using `NSString` method `stringWithFormat`.